# Fast upsert into duckdb

Tags: r, r-dbi, duckdb

I have a dataset where I need to upsert data (on conflict replace some *value* columns). As this is the bottleneck of an app, I want this to be fairly optimized. But duckdb is really slow compared to sqlite in this instance. What am I doing wrong here?

## MWE

A quick example is this table, where `id` and `name` are unique and where `val` and `created_at` are values which should be updated in a conflict.

I set up the table like this

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())
q <- "CREATE TABLE main (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  val REAL NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE(id, name)
)"
DBI::dbExecute(con, q)
```

Then I simulate some values to insert into the table

```
# Create a data frame
create_data <- function(N, k_letters) {
  data.frame(
    id = sample.int(100, N, replace = TRUE),
    name = replicate(N, paste(sample(letters, k_letters), collapse = "")),
    val = runif(N),
    created_at = Sys.time()
  ) |>
  # to take only unique values...
  dplyr::group_by(id, name) |> dplyr::slice(1) |> dplyr::ungroup()
}

set.seed(123)
df_orig <- create_data(10000, 2)
nrow(df_orig)
#> [1] 9285

DBI::dbAppendTable(con, "main", df_orig)
```

Now I simulate new data ...

```
set.seed(124)
new_data <- create_data(100000, 2)
nrow(new_data)
#>[1] 50902

# how many are in the original but remain as they are not in the new data?
anti_join(df_orig, new_data, by = c("id", "name")) |> nrow()
#> [1] 1971

# how many are overwritten by the new?
semi_join(df_orig, new_data, by = c("id", "name")) |> nrow()
#> [1] 7314

# how many are newly added
anti_join(new_data, df_orig, by = c("id", "name")) |> nrow()
#> [1] 43588
```

... and upsert it into the table

```
upsert_db <- function(con, data) {
  q <- "INSERT INTO test
    VALUES ($id, $name, $val, $created_at)
    ON CONFLICT (id, name)
    DO UPDATE SET val = excluded.val, created_at = excluded.created_at;"

  res <- dbSendStatement(con, q)
  dbBind(res, params = unname(as.list(data)))
  rr <- dbGetRowsAffected(res)
  dbClearResult(res)
  rr
}
t0 <- Sys.time()
upsert_db(con, new_data)
#> [1] 50902
difftime(Sys.time(), t0)
#> Time difference of 16.30046 secs
```

This works but is really slow, similar code with SQLite takes less than a second.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For duckdb, a looping insert is going to be much slower than using a bulk appender.

Using a bulk operation in this scenario is possible by using a temporary table to first load into, then `INSERT`.

```r
upsert_db <- function(con, data) {
  # create an empty table matching main
  ct <- "CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE stg as 
  SELECT * FROM main WHERE 1 = 2"

  dbExecute(con, ct)
  dbAppendTable(con, "stg", data)

  # merge the data between the two tables
  iq <- "INSERT INTO main
    select * from stg
    ON CONFLICT (id, name)
    DO UPDATE SET val = excluded.val, created_at = excluded.created_at;"
  rr <- dbExecute(con, iq)

  # drop the source merge table
  dq <- "DROP TABLE stg"
  dbExecute(con, dq)
  rr
}
```

By using a temp table and loading it with `dbAppendTable` we get much better performance for the `UPSERT` operation.

```r
t0 <- Sys.time()
upsert_db(con, new_data)
#> [1] 50902
difftime(Sys.time(), t0)
#> Time difference of 0.03464794 secs
```